# Calculate auto covariant term using focal function from raster package

Tags: raster, r, raster-calculator, autocorrelation, focal-statistics

I want to calculate the auto covariant by myself. At this point I found the function `focal` from `raster` package. Here I show I proceeded :

```
 glm_BEF_AUTO <- glm(as.formula (MODEL_FORM) ,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data=Data) # my glm before adding autocov variable 
  m48 <- matrix(1, nrow=7, ncol=7) #I choose here a neigbor matrix 7*7 
  m48[4,4] <- 0
  my_point <-  c(500000, 5600000) # arbitrary point just to compute the distance matrix 
  cells_a <- cellFromXY(ras_[[1]],my_point) # ras_ is one of my raster files juste to reconver the adjacent cells from it 
  xy_point <- xyFromCell(ras_[[1]], cells_a)
  a<- adjacent(ras_[[1]], cells=cells_a, directions=m48, pairs=FALSE)
  xy_a <- xyFromCell(ras_[[1]], a) 
  dist_to_a <- pointDistance(xy_a, xy_point , lonlat=FALSE)
  dist_to_a <- append(dist_to_a, 0, ((length(m48)-1)/2))
  d <- matrix(dist_to_a, nrow=dim(m48)[1], ncol=dim(m48)[2])
  inv.d <- 1/(d)
  inv.d [(dim(m48)[1]+1)/2,(dim(m48)[1]+1)/2] <- 0
  predic <- predict(Full_stack, glm_BEF_AUTO, type="response") #Full_stack represents raster stack of all my predictors
  #----------------------------------------------------------------
  autocov <- raster::focal(predic, w=inv.d, na.rm=T)
```

Where `predic` is the predicted occurrence probabilities raster and `inv.d` is inverse Euclidian distance matrix to the adjacent cells.  Is this way correct? I'm observing the same pattern between the probabilities and the autocov (see the attached figure[image]).

Comment: What is `glm_BEF_auto`?

Comment: @coconn41 it's the model before including the autocov variable. I used here a logistic regression.

Comment: @user1988 I think it is difficult to see if you did this correctly. You should post your full code, including those for making the inverse distance weights, to see if you did it correctly. I would say it is probably incorrect if the two maps have exactly the same pattern.

Comment: @coconn41 I added an example to show how I proceeded.

Comment: I suppose I am confused. I'm trying to decipher what you're doing but your example isn't completely reproducible. It seems that you've found cells that are adjacent to a specific point, and you want to apply a weight to these cells? You're using a raster, so shouldn't all of the points have the same weight because they are all adjacent, thus equidistant, from your "arbitrary point" at `c(500000, 5600000)`?

Comment: Actually, I want before estimating the autocov variable, calculate inverse-distance matrix that represents the inverse of the distance from the cell of the focal point to all the surrounding cells in adjacent matrix.It is a constant matrix and I can use it for all my pixels since I work by the pixels (cells) locations. That's why I chose an arbitrary point to compute that.  And I want to use this inverse matrix to calculate a weighted sum as autocov variable for each pixel (autocov_i= sum w_ij y_j).

Comment: Okay. I would suggest editing your question to: 1.) fully explain what you are attempting to do and your problem. 2.) Make your R code reproducible, i.e., try to recreate the problem with a dataset that everyone else may have access to, or, provide the data directly in your code. That way, even if I cannot help, someone else may be able to.

Comment: I think I understand more though. Should you be attempting to do the moving window aspect? I.e. - calculating the weights for all "focal" points? It seems that you only did it for `c(500000, 5600000)`.